# Reading in XML from webserivce request using HttpRequest

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, rest, soap

I have seen multiple posts online talking about how to read in XML data from a web request using HttpRequest, but I cannot seem to make it work or find any documentation on it. The closest I have gotten is to making it work is to enclose the xml in

< request >....< /request >

which is not acceptable for my case.

Is there anyway to send a raw string of xml to salesforce for manual parsing and not having to alter or encapsulate that string?

edit.

```
    < B:Envelope xmlns:B="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:A="theircustomuri" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       < SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-SEC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12">
          < SOAP-SEC:Signature SOAP:mustUnderstand="1">
             < Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:C="theircustomuri" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
                < SignedInfo>
                   < CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                   < SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                   < Reference URI="#Body">
                      < Transforms>
                         < Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                      < /Transforms>
                      < DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                      < DigestValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx< /DigestValue>
                   < /Reference>
                < /SignedInfo>
                < SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx< /SignatureValue>
                < KeyInfo>
                   < X509Data>
                      < X509Certificate />
                      < X509IssuerSerial>
                         < X509IssuerName>Oxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx< /X509IssuerName>
                         < X509SerialNumber>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx< /X509SerialNumber>
                      < /X509IssuerSerial>
                   < /X509Data>
                < /KeyInfo>
             < /Signature>
          < /SOAP-SEC:Signature>
       < /SOAP:Header>
       < B:Body id="Body">
          < B:Fault>
             < B:faultcode>Client.invalidData< /B:faultcode>
             < B:faultstring>invalidData< /B:faultstring>
             < B:detail>
                < faultdetails>detailed info< /faultdetails>
             < /B:detail>
          < /B:Fault>
          < A:AdditionalInfo version="2.0">
             < A:SenderID>FS000< /A:SenderID>
             < A:TargetID>F000BK< /A:TargetID>
          < /A:AdditionalInfo>
       < /B:Body>
    < /B:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you making a call *out* from Salesforce, or is someone else making a call *in* to Salesforce? Is the service REST or SOAP-based (you've tagged both)? Can you give a concrete example of the issue you're confronting?

Comment: We'd have to see a sample of what you're trying to parse to know exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is a callout into Salesforce that should be SOAP, but it doesn't meet Salesforce's standards for a soap message. One of the things would be having a custom namespace on the body data instead of the "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/....."

So I keep reading about people using custom rest services in salesforce to create a listener to manually parse the data, but i have been stuck for months.

Comment: @awh01 Are those tags literally `< B:Body>` with the leading whitespace? That wouldn't be valid XML. When I fix the whitespace issue, the XML parses just fine.

Comment: @sfdcfox No, there is no leading whitespace. The tags weren't showing in the code block when I didn't have the whitespace (I'm not aware of the escape character for xml in this codeblock)

Are you using rest or soap?

Comment: If I use @HttpPost with rest, I get this error:
[{"message":"Root element must be named 'request'","errorCode":"XML_PARSER_ERROR"}]

Comment: @sfdcfox When you say the xml parses just fine, do you mean in an XML validator? Because the XML is fine, but I can't get it to work in a SOAP message

Comment: @awh01 You wouldn't call it as SOAP, you'd sent a plain old message. If you're calling your method as a real SOAP message, you must conform to *Salesforce* SOAP model.

Comment: @sfdcfox How would one go about doing that? This is the envelope of a SOAP callout from a third party. They need an endpoint to send that to. How can I provided an endpoint from them to send this specific call?

Comment: Having thought about it more, I suspect that you're writing the Apex code with function parameters. You would need to use RestRequest.requestBody directly.

Comment: @sfdcfox This seems to be working for the most part, but I am trying to get it as an unauthenticated call through a force.com site. When I test it through Postman (as a POST) I get this response: METHOD_NOT_ALLOWEDHTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are DELETE,POST

If I add a GET method and run it as a POST, it works in postman, but the body is discarded. But if I run it as a GET in postman, is just gives me the HTML of the site's default vf page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is as @sfdcfox suggested. You can just create a rest endpoint without parameters (so salesforce doesn't try to automatically deserialize).

```
 @HttpPost
global static String doPost() {
    String soapRequestBody = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('OK');
    return 'OK';
}
```